# Can $f(z) = \sum_p \frac {z^p}{p^2}$ teach us about primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

In analytic number theory we always consider Dirichlet series.

So I wonder if other functions can offer any insight into primes ?

Ofcourse I am not talking about turning Dirichlet series into taylor series.

Also I am not talking about a special set of primes such as twins or $1 \mod 30$ but rather all the primes.
Guess that is close to the prime counting function then.

Does the function

$$f(z) = \sum_p \frac {z^p}{p^2}$$

where the sum is over all the primes $p$,

teach us anything about the primes ?

Can we reformulate the RH with (statements about) $f(z)$ ?

Comment: $z(z f’)’$  is discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441937/is-anything-known-about-the-power-series-sum-xp-for-p-prime). In particular it’s divergent sum renormalized values at the natural boundary are closely related to prime number races

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal thank you.  I will consider those sums and a different method. I need to think.  This post here is more about number theory than the "continuation".

Answer (score 2):

Today the prime number theorem is proved using the Dirichlet series $\sum \Lambda(n)/n^s$, where $\Lambda$ is the von Mangoldt function.  This is the negative log derivative $-\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)$, which allows us to use properties of $\zeta(s)$ to tell us about the behavior of $\psi(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} \Lambda(n)$.

In the early 20th century, Hardy & Littlewood were able to prove the prime number theorem using the power series $\sum_{n \geq 1} \Lambda(n)z^n$. The use of power series and trigonometric series to study questions about primes is still an active area: look up the circle method.

Once you see Dirichlet series uses to make deductions about primes, it's natural to ask if the "prime zeta-function" $\sum_p 1/p^s$ can be useful, but it really is the wrong object to regard as being of primary importance.  The lesson I want to make is that merely writing down a sum over primes shouldn't be expected to make that sum helpful to study primes.

The answer by Vesslin Dimitrov to the MO question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95743/why-could-mertens-not-prove-the-prime-number-theorem/208228#208228) might be inspiring. He discusses how results like the prime number theorem manifest themselves in error terms at different scales.

Comment: Yes not every sum over primes is equally interesting ofcourse.  But I think there might be a handful others that are not dirichlet series.
I have almost given up the prime zeta function as a tool btw.
My idea is that to get info about an infinite integer sequence they need to " generate or construct " something , as example like the euler product and the unique factorization link the primes with the integers. 

Your link shows how the mertens results are too weak, and thereby showing not every sum or product over primes automatically makes a very good study of the prime density.